# Reference template variable within Jinja expression

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a route defined like this:

```
@app.route('/magic/<filename>')
def moremagic(filename):
    pass
```

And now in a template I want to call that route using `url_for()` like so:

```html
<h1>you uploaded {{ name }}<h1>
<a href="{{ url_for('/magic/<filename>') }}">Click to see magic happen</a>
```

I have tried:

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('/magic', filename={{ name }}) }}">Click to see magic happen</a>
```

That throws a `jinja2.TemplateSyntaxError:  expected token  ':' got }`

Can anyone suggest how to get the `{{ name }}` that appears in the template into the `url_for()` so that when I click I call the correct `app.route`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Everything inside the `{{ ... }}` is a Python-like expression. You don't need to use another `{{ ... }}` inside that to reference variables.

Drop the extra brackets:

```html
<h1>you uploaded {{ name }}<h1>
<a href="{{ url_for('moremagic', filename=name) }}">Click to see magic happen</a>
```

(Note that the `url_for()` function takes the endpoint *name*, not a URL path; the name defaults to the name of the function, `moremagic` in your example).