# Nest braces in square brackets in a list with flask jinja2?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a route defined like that:

```
[...]
reports = session.query(Report)
    frames = session.query(Frame)
    return render_template('reports.html', reports = reports, frames = frames)
[...]
```

Once in the template *"reports.html"* I loop on *"reports"* like that (`{% for i in reports %}`)

And now in the loop I try to dynamically display a value in a list by **writing a Jinja expression inside the two square brackets of the list**:

```
[...]
<div>
{{frames[ {{i.frame_choice}} ].client_name}}
</div>
[...]
```

And I get this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Trying this time the jinja expression without the braces:

```
[...]
<div>
{{frames[ i.frame_choice ].client_name}}
</div>
[...]
```

I get this error:

```
UndefinedError: 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object' has no attribute u'0'
```

However `{{i.frame_choice}}` alone give me *"0"*, `{{frames[0].client_name}}` give me *"baroudeur"* but I can't merge them.

*"frames"* and *"reports"* are 2 lists dynamically created within a SQLAlchemy base, using python classes, and are not empty:

```
[...]
class Frame(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'frame'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_name = Column(String(250))
    client_adress = Column(String(250))
    client_phone = Column(String(10))
    client_mail = Column(String(250))


class Report(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'report'

    frame_choice = Column(String(250))
[...]
```

Is there a way to perform what I am trying to do ?

Thank you

This ([Reference template variable within Jinja expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024551/reference-template-variable-within-jinja-expression#)) is not even close to my problem and didn't help me.

Comment: hey there. I think we'll be closing this question as it is so broad, and there seems to be two or three questions at a time, and the problem really is unlikely to be reproducible by someone else. but don't be shy, make sure to try and be very clear on your next question!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the problem during a week and I suddenly understood. As you can see `frame_choice = Column(String(250))` is a string so I changed it in `frame_choice = Column(Integer)` and everything worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="{{url_for('static' , filename='uploads/'+file)}}" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think this is something near by what you need in <source src="{{url_for('static' , filename='uploads/'+file)}}" type="audio/mpeg">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).