# Block tag inside url_for() in Jinja2

Tags: python, frontend, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 to render my frontend (and python is on the backend). Each page will have a different image on its top, like this:

```
<header>
    <img src="static/img/pic1.png">
</header>
```

I used *url_for()* to get the correct path of my static folder:

```
<header>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/pic1.png') }}"> 
</header>
```

So far, so good. But I would like to put a block inside the filename parameter, so I can reuse the code and only overwrite the name of the image. This is what I'm trying:

```
<header>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='{% block img %}img/pic1.png{% endblock %}') }}">
</header>
```

But it doesn't work, this is the final code that is rendered by Jinja2:

```
<header>
    <img src="/static/%7B%25%20block%20img%20%25%7Dimg/pic1.png%7B%25%20endblock%20%25%7D">
</header>
```

As you can see, Jinja2 doesn't recognize the *block* tag as an expression and treats it as a string. If it worked, I would be able to set the picture of each page only using this code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block img %}img/pic2.png{% endblock %}
...
```

Could someone help, please? By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024551/reference-template-variable-within-jinja-expression) post didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a **macro** to define a kind of function in your template. See this topic in 
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/

```
{% macro header_img(name) -%}
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=name) }}">
{%- endmacro %}
```

You can put this macro in an util template and [import](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import) it in each page.

Use the syntax:

```
<header>{{ header_img("your_image.jpg") }}</header>
```

Comment: And how other pages would reuse this code to generate *img/pic2* for example?

Comment: Well I add links to the doc (which is very good) and a small example.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I don't have to import if I only extends the template that has the macro. If you could, please, put a simples example without import, I'll select your post as the answer to serve for further reference.