# Replace Jinja2 block inside string

Tags: flask, jinja2

I want to replace a part of a `url_for` link with a template block that specifies the filename. I followed something similar to [Block tag inside url_for() in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947941/block-tag-inside-url-for-in-jinja2). But I want to put the image in the base templates `main` block.

This is the `base` file:

```
{% macro error_img(name) -%}
<img class="center-block" viewBox="0 0 60 55" width="300" height="300"
     src="{{ url_for('static', filename=name) }}" alt=""/>
{%- endmacro %}

{% block main %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col"> <!-- I want the image HERE -->
      {{ error_img(name) }}
    </div>1
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the child template:

```
{% extends "errors/base.html" %}

{{ error_img("media/errors/404.svg") }}
```

But I get an image with the url: `http://localhost:5000/static/`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason a `block` is required around the `macro`:

`base.html`

```
{% macro error_img(name) -%}
<img class="center-block" viewBox="0 0 60 55" width="300" height="300"
     src="{{ url_for('static', filename=name) }}" alt=""/>
{%- endmacro %}

{% block main %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col"> <!-- I want the image HERE -->
      {% block img %}
        {{ error_img(name) }}
      {% endblock%}
    </div>
  </div>
```

`child.html`

```
{% extends "errors/base.html" %}

{% block img %}
{{ error_img('media/errors/404.svg') }}
{% endblock %}
```