# Flask url_for() with arguments

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, jinja2, url-routing

I'm learning Flask and I got stuck here.

**How to make links for searched results with arguments ( parameter ) ?**

My app searches for books and renders them on an HTML page using Flask and Jinja2 along with HTML only.

So my HTML has only this function:

```
 <ul>
   {% for x in lk1 %}
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('bookPage'}}">{{ x[2] }}   (by) {{ x[3] }}  (year) :  {{ x[4] }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

> where `lk1` is the list of books gathered by Flask from SQL
>   and `x` are the raw info from SQL database

Now in page `bookpage.html` it's empty I need to pass arguments with the URL so I can render them on the page or fetch the rest of info about this book and render it in the book page also if you could help me understand how to make URL of the book title which is according to my code it's `{{ x[2] }}`
I saw ppl doing something like `<url_titl>` but I don't know how it works

Thank you!

Comment: Url_for is FOR THE URLS DEFINED IN YOUR APP if you are setting an externa URL you probably Just need the strings nd href=string

Answer (score 7):

I think, you have to learn information about creating variable url with flask and jinja.

Example of variable url.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    {% for x in lk1 %}
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('bookPage', title=x[2] }}">{{ x[2] }}   (by) {{ x[3] }}  (year) :  {{ x[4] }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Python**

```
@app.route('/books/<title>' )
# the name of this function have to be used in 
# url_for ('nameOfFunction',  name_of_variable_part_of_url=some_internal_variable)
def bookPage(title):
     # code, that will creat yourlist
     # book.html - template for book
     # listofvariables - variables for book's page
     # 
     return render_template ("book.html", listofvariables=yourlist)
```

Link to a similar question: [Reference template variable within Jinja expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024551/reference-template-variable-within-jinja-expression)

Update: to use many variables in an url you have to change html and python.

**Html:**

```
<a href="{{ url_for('bookPage', title=x[2], heading=x[3]) }}">all your text </a>
```

**Python:**

```
@app.route('/books/<title>-<heading>' ) 
def bookPage(title, heading):
```

Comment: thanks alot that worked !! but can i pass more than just the title ? i keep getting an error when i add more than 1 argument >>>>>----------<li><a href="{{ url_for('bookPage',title=x[2] ,year=x[3] )}}">{{X}}</a></li>-------- error is : ---- missing 1 required positional argument

also please could you provide me with link for a good resource "creating variable url with flask and jinja." i cant find something that have valuable info like for_url()

Comment: html: `<a href="{{ url_for('bookPage', title=x[2], heading=x[3]) }}">all your text </a>` and python, 2 lines: `@app.route('/books/<title>-<heading>' )` and
`def bookPage(title, heading):`

Answer (score 3):

```
@app.route('books', methods=['GET', 'POST')
def books():
    book_list = Book.query.all()
    return render_template('books.html', book_list=book_list)
```

Template;

```
<ul>
{% for x in book_list %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('bookpage', title=x.title, book_id=x.id }}">{{ x.title }}   (by) {{ x.author }}  (year) :  {{ x.year }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

To get the url with the title, your view function should be as shown below. The book `id` is important since books can have the same titles hence they cannot be used as unique identifiers.

```
@app.route('bookpage/<int:book_id>/<string:title>', methods=['GET', 'POST')
def bookpage(title=None, book_id=None):
```

I'd suggest you use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#quickstart) and have Book as an object as shown below and you will be able to access attributes as shown in the Jinja template.

```
class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey)
    title = db.Column(Text)
    author = db.Column(Text)
```

If you want to access book pages you can have a One to Many model for Books and Pages i.e. one book has many pages if you are the one uploading the content.