# Flask - Return an url from a python function to html templates

Tags: python, html, flask

I've a function that prepare an url:

```
def my_url():
    params = {"client_id": CLIENT_ID,
             "response_type": "code",
             "state": "abcdefg",
             "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI}
url = "https://ssl.myapi.com/?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
return url
```

How can I insert the generated link, in my templates?
Eg:

> < a href=my_url> login < /a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference template variable within Jinja expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024551/reference-template-variable-within-jinja-expression)

Answer (score 5):

The render_template function accepts arbitrary variables.

Simply:

```
render_template(‘index.html’, myurl=myurl)
```

And you can now access myurl from your template.

```
<a href=“{{myurl}}”> login </a>
```