# How to use jinja template with mix of params and airflow inbuilts

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, jinja2

I am trying to create a SQL template for Snowflake where I am trying to load a S3 file using SnowflakeOperator and s3 file is provided as xcom variable from upstream task.

Here is an example template for SQL

```
create or replace temp table {{ params.raw_target_table }}_tmp
as
select *
from '@{{ params.stage_name }}/{{ params.get_s3_file }}'
file_format => '{{ params.file_format }}'
;
```

`params.get_s3_file` is set to use ti like `{{{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="foo", key="file_uploaded_to_s3")}}}}`

I understand that in the template if used directly, it will work if it is **not** coming from params, but I want it to be configurable so I can use it with multiple dags/tasks.

Ideally I want this to work

```
create or replace temp table {{ params.raw_target_table }}_tmp
as
select *
from '@{{ params.stage_name }}/{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="{{params.previous_task}}", key="file_uploaded_to_s3")}}'
file_format => '{{ params.file_format }}'. --note the nested structure
;
```

So it resolves `params.previous_task` first and then gets the xcom values. Not sure how to instruct it do it.

Comment: => `{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=params.previous_task, key="file_uploaded_to_s3") }}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference template variable within Jinja expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024551/reference-template-variable-within-jinja-expression)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I have another related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948237/use-airflow-jinja-with-params-to-update-sql

Answer (score 1):

When you use `{{ <some code> }}` jinja execute the code during the runtime, so this code is just hard python code (not template) executed during the runtime.

`{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="{{params.previous_task}}", key="file_uploaded_to_s3")}}` will try to pull the xcom with key `file_uploaded_to_s3` from the task `{{params.previous_task}}` which doesn't exist. Instead of providing a string as `task_ids`, you can provide `params.previous_task` and jinja will replace it by the value of `previous_task` from the `params` dict:

```sql
create or replace temp table {{ params.raw_target_table }}_tmp
as
select *
from '@{{ params.stage_name }}/{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=params.previous_task, key="file_uploaded_to_s3")}}'
file_format => '{{ params.file_format }}'. --note the nested structure
;
```