# Use Airflow Jinja with params to update SQL

Tags: airflow, jinja2

I have a sql template file and want to create  DYNAMIC S3 KEY for data unload (SNOWFLAKEOPERATOR)
SQL in template file

```
copy into @dummy_stage/{{ params.s3_key}} from ....
```

I am passing params as
 `params: {"s3_key":"foo/blah/{{ execution_date }}/test_file.csv`

- I am aware that params is not a template field in SnowflakeOperator and hence rendering the templated SQL will be tricky or not possible but I feel like I am missing something here.
- I am aware I can update SQL file to include {{execution_date}} but I want to make the process more generic so looking for ways to pass in params

Excepted output:
`copy into @dummy_stage/foo/blah/2023-08-21/test.csv from ....`

Comment: try to create class SnowflakeOperatorEx that inherit SnowflakeOperator and only change template_fields: Sequence[str] = ("sql", "parameters"). in airflow 2.7 SnowflakeOperator is depcreated and you need to use SQLExecuteQueryOperator which has prameters in its template_fields

Answer (score 0):

Did get your question, when you create a stage and give role access of that stage, it automatically lets you write at that location, for ex

copy into @my_stage/location
from (blah blah..........)

will work, there will be no need to specify additional key